# Android Save Grid View State

Tags: android, android-gridview

Android Development - Grid View Scroll Position
Hi, i am trying to create a wallpaper application using Grid View. But there is one problem, When i click on the Grid View it takes to a different activity and when i press back button, i have to scroll the Grid View again from top to bottom. I want that  the grid view should remain at the same position where it was when i clicked an image on Grid View.

Please Help.
Many Thanks !

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);


    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class       
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    /**
     * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be scrolled to the exact scrolling value? Also, what should happen if the device has changed its orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Code that definitely works !

At the top.
you need to create a static variable index.
and gridview as private.

```
static int index;
private GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onResume(){

    gridView.setSelection(index);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){  
    index = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In onResume(),

```
gridView.setSelection(index, 0);
```

in onPause, add the following line to the end:

```
index = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: It is not working in Grid View. please help me i think you have helped me a lot by these few line but it's not working.

Comment: GridView doesn't have method setSelectionFromTop

Comment: Downvoted because grid view does not have setSelectionFromTop